# How to handle a missing lat long values from AJAX response? How to detect and give appropriate alert to the user?

Tags: json, server, format, response, handle

I am getting a JSON response from an AJAX call like this below

```
{"metadata":{"assetStatusAvailable":false},"data":[{"id":"209880948","name":"1:Periodic Report","domainObjectType":"assetmessageevent","domainObjectTypeId":"assetmessageevent_209880948","heading":null,"latitude":,"longitude":,"isAlertEvent":false,"eventTime":"2016-10-03T04:53:02","assetCategory":"Underground Tank 15000GL","configurationName":"Tank","mapCurrentSymbol":"","asset":{"id":"209843212","name":"TANK001","domainObjectType":"tank","domainObjectTypeId":"tank_209843212"}}]}
```

Here latitude and longitude is missing so it's not parsed and hence throws an error. How to handle such scenario and give appropriate message to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Use following function to check a blank value and null value of latitude, longitude

```
var checkBlankValue(){
        $.each(obj.data, function(key, value){
            if (key=='latitude' || key=='longitude'){
                if (value === "" || value === null){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Check latitude, longitude blank value in data if any blank value in data then above function return false then you are able to display message to user.

Something like this

```
if (!checkBlankValue){
    return "your message";
}
```